# How do I use only one INPUT TYPE = "text" to conduct two surveys

Tags: html

How do I use only one INPUT TYPE = "text" to conduct two surveys

```
<FORM method="GET" action="http://www.youtube.com/results?q="> 
</A><br> <A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/"> </A> 
**<INPUT TYPE="text" name="q" size=25 maxlength=270 value="" background-color="#ff00ff" >** 
<INPUT type="submit" name="btnY" VALUE="Youtube"> 
</FORM>  

<FORM method="GET" action="http://www.google.com/search"> 
</A> <A HREF="http://www.google.com/"> </A> 
**<INPUT TYPE="text" name="q" size=25 maxlength=270 value="" background-color="#ff00ff">** 
<INPUT type="submit" name="btnG" VALUE="Google"> 
</FORM>
```

Comment: You could create two frames in which you display the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use somethink like this

**html**

```
**<INPUT id="inputLink" TYPE="text"size=25 maxlength=270 background-color="#ff00ff" >** 
<a id="searchOnYoutube" href=""><button>Youtube</button></a>
<a id="searchOnGoogle" href=""><button>Google</button></a>
```

**and jQuery**

```
$("#inputLink").keyup( function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    $("#searchOnYoutube").attr("href", "http://www.youtube.com/results?q="+search);
    $("#searchOnGoogle").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/search="+search);
});
```

jQuery keyup function refresh the links of Google button and Youtube button
Try on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p22fw/

Comment: perfect, thanks! 
correction is "https://www.google.com.br/search?q="

Comment: I don't know why -1. Glad to have helped you.